CodeIgniter error messages displaying differently between local environment and server environment with Docker
I'm encountering an issue where error messages in my CodeIgniter 4 application are displaying differently between my local development environment and my server environment where Docker is being used.
In my local environment (Windows host), when I encounter a validation error, such as a required field not being filled in, the error message includes the variable name, like "The Username field is required."

However, when I deploy the same application to my server environment (Ubuntu host with Docker), the error message does not include the variable name; instead, it just says "The field is required."

Both environments are running PHP 8.3, and I've ensured that the CodeIgniter version is the same (3.x). I've checked the PHP error reporting settings, and they seem to be consistent between environments.
my docker composer file
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/mysql/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        environment:
            MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MARIADB_DATABASE: ${MARIADB_DATABASE}

        volumes:
            - ./db_data:/usr/data
        ports:
            - "3309:3306"
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/apache/Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
            - ./apache_log:/var/log/apache2
       
        ports:
            - 84:80
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8084:8080

my docker file
# use php 8.3 apache image
FROM php:8.3-apache
# Update it
RUN apt-get update

# install necessary libraries
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    curl \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    g++

# install docker extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar \
    pdo_mysql \
    mysqli

# set up document root for apache
COPY docker/apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

# start with base php config, then add extensions
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

# composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN composer self-update

COPY . /var/www/html/

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html && \
    chmod -R 755 /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

CodeIgniter  controller  for validation
  $rules = [
                'username' => [
                    'rules' => 'required|string|min_length[5]|max_length[30]',
                    'errors' => [
                        'required' => lang('validation.required', ['field' => lang('users.usersInputUsername')]),
                    ],
                ],

I examined the config.php and database.php files in my CodeIgniter application to see if there are any environment-specific configurations that could affect error message formatting. However, I couldn't find anything

It is just the difference between your local machine OS and the server OS. Usually server operating systems doesn't support some stdin or stdout decorations for the sake of performance.

@UbaydulloIbrohimov do you know how to fix it ?

I don't think so as it is not an error. But It can be corrected by digging into your server's shell configuration or just install some advanced shell program.
